# Is there a way how to identify class of overloaded operator[] in c++?

Tags: c++, templates, types, operator-overloading, auto

Let say we have a class with an operator [] as follows

```
class MyClass
{
//...
public:
    TYPE operator[](const size_t idx) const
    {
        //... Implementation
    }
}
```

Now i want to read `TYPE` and use it as a template argument for another class. One may use a trick

```
template<class T>
class OtherClass
{
    //...
}

template<class T>
auto generator(const T& element)
{
    return OtherClass<T>(); 
} 

int main(void)
{
    MyClass myclass;
    auto resulted_class = generator(myclass[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

This should create an `OtherClass` with template `TYPE` from `MyClass` and copy it into `resulted_class`.

And now the question. Is it possible to achieve the same but without generic call of [] operator for index value 0 or any specific index value? The point is that it is not guaranteed that operator [] is defined for a specific value. We just need to extract `TYPE` if possible.

In other words, if we use a class like `std::vector<double>` we want to extract that `double` from that class. But without further knowledge about `std::vector`. The only thing we know is that there is a definition of [] operator within.

Comment: Yes (see answer), but keep in mind that `std::vector` has `value_type` defined already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes:

```
using T = std::decay_t<decltype(myclass[0])>;
```

The expression inside `decltype` is not evaluated. In fact, you don't need an instance:

```
using T = std::decay_t<decltype(std::declval<MyClass>()[0])>;
```

See [`std::decay`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay), [`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) and [`std::declval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval)

Comment: It seems that even just initialisation as

OtherClass<decltype(std::declval<MyClass>()[0])> resulted_class

is sufficient. Even without std::dacay it works.

Comment: @MarekBasovník yes, of course. `using T = ...` was just an example to get the type. You can use the type however you like. It's a bit like creating a variable vs inline using the expression.

Comment: @MarekBasovník it works without `std::decay`. But for `std::vector` for example, the type is going to be `double&` or `double const&`, not just `double`.